# why does sympy.simplify change the random state

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy

The following test fails:

```
def test_sympy_simplify():
    import sympy
    import random
    random.seed(42)
    state = random.getstate()
    expr = "sin(x)**2 + cos(x)**2"
    sympy.simplify(expr)
    assert state == random.getstate()
```

Why does this fail? Why does simplify need random?
It also seems that the state changes differently between multiple runs of this snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I chased down this problem once: https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201302/hunting_a_random_bug.html

It's because importing sympy imports its test helpers, and the test helpers have a definition like this:

```
class SymPyTests(object):
    def __init__(self, ..., seed=random.random()):
        #...
        self._seed = seed
```

Read the blog post for how I found it, and other aspects of the comedy of errors.